# How to handle Ctrl+C with <signal.h>

Tags: c, signals, kernel-module

I'm attempting communications between a user-level program and a kernel module. My user-level program starts a timer then goes to sleep and is woken up by the kernel module when the time is completed, then a message is printed.

The problem I'm having is if I `Ctrl+C` while the user-level program is sleeping, when the timer expires it still prints the message (which I don't want it to do). This is my first time using `<signal.h>` and I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement this. I found a website which said that `SIGHUP` is the signal that is sent when `Ctrl+C` is pressed, so I think I should implement some case for this signal in my `sighandler()` function, but I'm pretty lost at the moment on how to go about this. Here's what I've pieced together so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sighandler(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char line[256];
    int lenNum, lenName;
    struct sigaction action, oa;

    int pFile, oflags;
    pFile = open("/dev/mytimer", O_RDWR);
    if (pFile < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "mytimer module isn't loaded\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup signal handler
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
    action.sa_handler = sighandler;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGIO, &action, NULL);
    fcntl(pFile, F_SETOWN, getpid());  // process ID o owner saved to filp->f_owner
    oflags = fcntl(pFile, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(pFile, F_SETFL, oflags | FASYNC);  // enable asynchronous notification


    // Check if timer set
    if (argc >= 4 && strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0) {
        lenNum = strlen(argv[2]);
        lenName = strlen(argv[3]);
        char *ptr;
        int i;
        i = asprintf(&ptr, "%s %s %s", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
        write(pFile, ptr, i+1); 
        while (read(pFile, line, strlen(line)) != 0) {  //257?
            printf("%s", line);
        }   
        free(ptr); 
        //printf("Sleep!\n");
        pause();
        printf("%s\n", argv[3]);
    }

    // List all active timers
    else if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-l") == 0) {
        char *ptr;
        int i;
        i = asprintf(&ptr, "%s 0", argv[1]);
        write(pFile, ptr, i);
        while (read(pFile, line, strlen(line)) != 0) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        free(ptr);
    }
    close(pFile);
    return 0;
    }

    // SIGIO handler
    void sighandler(int signo) {
        //printf("Awaken!\n");
        /* maybe something like this?
        if (signo == SIGHUP) {
            // clear timer
        } */
     }
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to check after writing the signal handler?

Comment: `man sigaction [...]If SA_SIGINFO is specified in sa_flags, then sa_sigaction  (instead  of sa_handler)  specifies  the  signal-handling function for signum.[...]`

Comment: Usually, SIGINT is sent on ctrl+c